# Using enum for creating new instances of a subclass in python

Tags: java, python, oop, enums, abstract-base-class

I have a following Java Code where enum data type is used to create instances of the base class as following:
Main Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class Element{
    static enum elements{
         quad8{Element create(){return new ElementQuad2D();}};
         abstract Element create();
    }
    public static Element newElement (String name){
         el=elements.valueOf(name);
         return el.create();
    }
    public Element (String name, int nind, int nstress){
        this.name = name;
        /*Do Something Else*/
    }
}
```

SubClass:

```
class ElementQuad2D extends Element{
    public ElementQuad2D(){
    super("quad8",8,4);
    }
}
```

How to create enum type as above such that I can create the instance of different subclass based on element name like "quad8" in PYTHON?

Comment: **why?** This seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? You are trying to take a Java design-pattern and throw it at Python, and there is probably an easier way to do whatever it is you are trying to achieve here

Comment: What I want to achieve is that when I call the method "newElement" with the name as parameter, say "quad8", I should be able to call the constructor of the subclass "ElementQuad2D()" from the enum "elements". My current implementation in Python involves bunch of if else statements which would be problematic, if I implement many such element types. I don't want exact implementation, but something close to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with a dictionary from a string to the class. The use of subclasses doesn't play a role here:

```
class Element: pass

class ElementQuad2D(Element): pass

mapping = {'quad8': ElementQuad2D}
obj = mapping['quad8']()
print(obj)
#  <__main__.ElementQuad2D object at 0x01D70BD0>
```